# Filter and select in dplyr: remove extra step

Tags: r, dplyr

When I filter a dataframe using dplyr, there is an extra step that I need to perform (see code below). can I do something to not have this last row?

```
df <- df_1 %>%
  filter(col_1 %in% mylist) %>%
  select(col_2) %>%
  unique()
df <- df$col_2 # extra step
```

Both cols are of type `chr`.

Comment: Use `... %>% pull(col_2) %>% unique()` instead. If not working, please give a reproducible example.

Comment: btw: you could also: `df_1 %>%
  filter(col_1 %in% mylist) %>%
  select(col_2) %>%
  unique() %>% .[["col_2"]]`. I recommend using markus way.

Comment: Did you try %<>% operator?